# NetSuite : criteria for multi-select field

Tags: netsuite

How to pass a "noneof None" filter in a saved-search for any multi-select field. I want to get only those records whose multi-select field is having some value in it. For select field this criteria works, but for multi-select it is not working.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are inconsistent for that sort of search.

What I do is I usually try the obvious search (noneof '@NONE@') but if that doesn't work then I'll do a not empty on the multi-select field's target record internali id

In the advanced search editor in the criteria tab start to select the Filter field.
At the bottom of the field list are all the related records find one like:

> My Multi-Select (Custom Field) Fields...

Select that and find the internal id or name field

Use 'is not empty' for the description.

This generally works.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this to a formula (text). Your formula can pull in your multi-select field, and then look for "is not empty".

Answer (score 0):

this is the filter, put "NOT" before the array.

```
var searchCreate = search.create({
        type: "customer",
        filters:
           [
              "NOT",
              ["custentity_rsc_item_dependente","noneof", "@NONE@"]
           ],
        columns:
           [
              "internalid",
              "custentity_enl_legalname",
              "custentity_rsc_item_dependente",
           ]
     });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).